# XCode 4 automatic navigation to another view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, navigation

In Xcode 4...
I would like to know how to do automatic redirection (or navigation) to another UIViewController after a specific time
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
     [self performSelector:@selector(yourRedirectMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]
```